# How to set the 4000 users and 1 hour duration using JMETER

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter I have a scenario like
Load tested with 4000 users and 1 hour duration
759965 requests made and out of which one request failed on an average 18894.13 requests made per second.

This was the earlier scenario and I want to make the same scenario again with the above information. Can someone guide me how to set up the environment and also the results. I have designed my script using Co-relation with the help regular expression extractor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOUhx.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) the configuration would be something like:

[image]

It would also be a good idea to use some [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) so the load would increase gradually and you could correlate increasing load with other metrics like response time or transactions per second.

You might also want to use one of [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) which can be installed as [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), they provide easy visual way to define the number of threads, test duration, ramp-up, ramp-down, time to hold the load, eventual [spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing), etc.

Once you define your desired workload you should run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), with regards to the test results the easiest option is to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)